# Change FROM name in mail inbox when sending email through Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 and in FROM field, I am writing `[your-name] <your-email>`

I have a few queries:

1. It throws error Invalid Mailbox Syntax is used. Screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/23keni5 No problem if the default **FROM** email is the actual domain's email ID.
2. When I receive email in my inbox (FYI, its a company email ID to which I am sending the email using CF7), the FROM field shows "**me**" instead of the actual sender name which should be ideally `[your-name]` i.e actual sender name who fills up the CF7. How can I change the FROM in my email inbox to be the actual sender name. Screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/23kg4u7

Please help me resolve the issues.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot showing your Mail setup with the tags.

Comment: Sorry. Didnt get you. Could you please clarify which screenshot are you asking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 works like shortcodes.  Your syntax should be

```
[your-name] <[your-email]>
```

As long as the field `your-email` is of type `email`

Comment: Thanks. It worked and resolved my 1st query.

Comment: You could accept this as the answer then ;)